Mac OS Sonoma can't access Windows DNS server
New user to Mac. We have a few at work so I picked a somewhat newer one up so I can get familiar with it.
At home I have a standard Windows Domain with a Windows DNS server running on Windows Server 2022. It's on my primary subnet, 10.0.0.0/24 (specifically, 10.0.0.215). As of now I do not have a second DNS server on the domain.
The Mac and a Windows 11 PC are on the same UniFi wireless network, different subnet: 10.0.10.0/26. The Mac has 10.0.10.43 and the Windows PC has 10.0.10.27.
Both can ping the DNS Server at 10.0.0.215, the Unifi Firewall is correct. I can ping all machines by IP back and forth. However, the Mac can't see the DNS service at all on 10.0.0.215 and can't resolve any local hostnames, like the domain name or any servers set as static DNS by FQDN. The Windows 11 machine can (and is domain joined, if that matters).
I've checked in the network settings of both machines, they are receiving the correct DNS servers via DHCP, 10.0.0.215, 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1. The Mac can see the internet and resolve internet hostnames like google.com and even superuser.com (I'm posting this from the Mac, actually). The DNS server has port 53 UDP and TCP wide open inbound.
Before I upgraded this Mac it was running Mac OS 11.3? I think? and could see my local DNS. Now it's running Sonoma 14.5.

Make sure you're not using .local as your TLD. The IETF has reserved it for mDNS and it is not a valid TLD for traditional unicast DNS. The IETF has reserved home.arpa as the TLD for private home unicast DNS. If that doesn't fix it, please edit your Question to include the output of scutil --dns, cat /etc/resolv.conf, dns-sd -G v4v6 hostname, and dig @10.0.0.215 hostname (where "hostname" is a valid FQDN that you've created an A or AAAA record for in your Windows DNS server.

I did a bit more digging and saw some Active Directory errors related to sync and DNS wouldn't serve because of it. Once I corrected those, all DNS operations were good.
I suspect the Windows machine had some cache still left which is why the DNS worked on there and not on the Mac. The Mac is new, the Windows 11 PC has been connected to this network since I re-built it a couple months ago.
